# What does ChannelFuture complete actually mean?

Tags: netty

Please excuse this numpty question, but when I do

```
ChannelFuture future = channel.write(message);
     future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
         public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
         }
     }
```

what do I know about the state of the message in the operationComplete() method? For example does it mean that the message has arrived at its destination? Or does it mean that the message has passed through the pipeline and is now somewhere in the ether on its way to its destination or does it mean something else?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message was written to the remote peer or it failed. So if you get a success here you can be sure that the message was transmitted.

Comment: does this mean that the remote peer downloaded the message completely?

Comment: Only means that it was written to the network stack. If you want to be 100 % sure the remote peer has received everything you need to implement some kind of acknowledge in your protocol